# Forbidden error 403 with React and Django

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, cors

I'm trying implement a login form where I'm passing the username and password to backend but I'm getting a 403 forbidden request error. Here is my frontend code where I'm sending username and password along with header named 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
const login = (username, password) => {
  return axios
    .post(
      API_URL + "signin/",
      {
        username: "test@test.com",
        password: "password",
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }

      return response. Data;
    });
};
```

This is my settings.py file in backend:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ......
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    ..........
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
```

And this is the views.py file:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def signin(request):
    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    print(username,"  ",password)

    return JsonResponse(username)
```

I'm trying to debug this error from the past few hours but haven't found a solution yet. On trying to debug, sometimes I also get the CORS error when I make a few changes to the settings.py file.

I tried searching for answers on stack overflow but those solutions didn't work for me. I know it should be a minor issue but am not able to spot it.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't belong in a request.

Comment: What precedes `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE` list? The order matters and CORS middleware needs to appear high on in this list (in front of any authenticated middleware).